# Critial Error: Site xxx does not need to be upgraded

Tags: upgrade, 2013, installation, tfs

I get this critical error once a day in the Windows Event log.

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCreateUpgradeEvalSitesJobDefintion
>   (ID 129be972-4ff0-4de7-a95e-6cbd15509b73) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Site h ttp://tfs01/sites/DefaultCollection-eval does not need to be
>   upgraded.

How do I go about resolving this error?

Update 1: 
[image]

Comment: In Central Administration, click Upgrade and Patch Management, and then click Review Database Status. Do any of the databases require attention or have a message other than "No Action Required"?

Comment: No, please see update 1 screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Its only, that two jobs get start together, its false positive error.